# how to combine multiple one band rasters to get a single rasterLayer with multibands in r program

Tags: r, raster

I have 4 single band raster, I want to combine them into a single rasterLayer with 4 bands rather than RaterStack. how should I finish this in r program?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: library(raster)
r <- raster(nrows=10,ncols=10)
r[] <- rnorm(100)
stk <- stack(r,r,r)
I would like combine these three single band raster into a singe rasterLayer with 3 bands, but stack function can not work. The format that I want is as follow

f <- system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster")
raster(f)